# upgrade to Chrome 48 removes SVGGraphicsElement.getTransformToElement()

Tags: jquery, html, dom

After upgrading chrome to version 48 - Where ever i have used :

```
SVGGraphicsElement.getTransformToElement()
```

in js;

I am getting js error :

> TypeError: elem.getTransformToElement is not a function(…)

How can i fix this one ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it !

found answer @ https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/192
For anyone running into this problem , this is current work around by rd-secretstuff:

```
// include this after webcomponents.js
// if the shadow dom polyfill is used...
if (window.ShadowDOMPolyfill)
{
    var SVGElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    SVGElement.__proto__.getTransformToElement = function getTransformToElement(p_Element)
    {
        return window.ShadowDOMPolyfill.unwrap(this).getTransformToElement(window.ShadowDOMPolyfill.unwrap(p_Element));
    };
}
```